# Docker-compose recreating containers, lost data

Tags: docker

In my attempt to extract some logs from a container I edited my `docker-compose.yml` adding an extra mount pointing to those logs.

After running docker-compose up and recreating the respective image I found out that all of the log files were gone, as the container was completely replaced (something which is quite obvious to me now)

Is there a way to recover the old container?

Also: the docker volumes live under `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`, where are the root file systems of containers?

Here is a snippet of the docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    some_app:
      image: some_image:latest
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - some_image_logs:/var/log 

volumes:
  some_image_logs: {}
```

Comment: Can you post your `docker-compose.yml` here?

Comment: @Yuankun `some_image_logs` was added later. And I innocently assumed it will copy the existing files to that volume

Comment: Some apps print the logs to STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: I see what you mean. Unfortunately this was a custom app that did not do that